# When using grep from VIM, how to jump to results?

Tags: linux, command-line, vim

When using the grep plugin to VIM, I can search the current directory for all occurrences of a string within a set of files, like this:

```
:grep Ryan *.txt
```

This outputs something like this:

```
file1.txt:3:Ryan was here
file2.txt:10:Ryan likes VIM
file3.txt:5:superuser.com is a fav of Ryan
(1 of 3): Ryan was here
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I press enter, it just takes me back to my editor. What I really want to do is be able to open up one of those files and jump to the place where the string was found. Is there a way to do this? The `1 of 3` part makes me think there's a way to tab through the results, but I don't know what commands are available to me. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you press ENTER, you should be looking at line 3 of file1.txt. To jump to the next match, execute `:cn`; to jump to the previous match, execute `:cp`. Executing `:copen` will open a window containing the list of matches. Move the cursor to the desired match and press ENTER to jump to that match.

For more on using `:grep`, see

```
:help grep
:help quickfix.txt
```

Typing `:cn` and `:cp` to move forward and backward in the quickfix list can be awkward, so I use these mappings:

```
nmap <silent> <C-N> :cn<CR>zv
nmap <silent> <C-P> :cp<CR>zv
```

Also, the `:grep` command is not a plugin; it's part of Vim.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! BTW, can you do a recursive search through folders with vim grep?

Comment: As long as you are running on a Unix system, you can add whatever arguments to Vim's `:grep` that you would add to a `grep` command executed from the shell. So, you could do a recursive search through all .txt files in and below the current directory with `:grep -R --include=*.txt Ryan .`. You can also perform a recursive search using Vim's `:vimgrep` command, but the arguments are different and I seldom use because it is slower than `:grep`.